# Install LAMP and Zend Framework on Server Version (EC2)

Tags: server, lamp, aws

Does anyone have a good step-by-step guide to setting up a server version of Ubuntu as a LAMP server?  Preferably with Zend Framework installed?

I have been working on a local workstation with the Desktop version of Ubuntu, and have setup AMP and Zend Framework a few times.  Now I'm ready to push a beta live and I've got myself an AWS account with an EC2 server.  Domain names are routing there.

I know that the process for setting up the server version of Ubuntu will be much the same as setting up the Desktop version, but since the terminal is not second nature to me, I thought I'd ask this question in the interests of eliminating one of the hurdles.  Also, I don't have a lot of time to do it in...

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guntbert, that was helpful.  Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

One very good guide for LAMP on Ubuntu Server is the [Ubuntu Server Guide - LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lamp-applications.html).